# Is Logback also affected by the Log4j zero-day vulnerability issue in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback

As I understand it, Logback is written by the same authors. Our applications are using Logback instead. Is there a chance that Logback is also affected by the exploit in Log4j?

This is critical for our organisation.

Comment: This question is not a resource recommendation question. The close reason is false.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From the [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot):

> Spring Boot users are only affected by this vulnerability if they have switched the default logging system to Log4J2. The `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-api` jars that we include in `spring-boot-starter-logging` cannot be exploited on their own. Only applications using `log4j-core` and including user input in log messages are vulnerable.

*Useful explanation points:*

`log4j-to-slf4j` is an adapter between the [Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) API and [SLF4J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLF4J). It indeed brings `log4j-api`, but it does not bring `log4j-core`, so our starter is not affected by this vulnerability.

Comment: Spring blog was updated, that logback released version 1.2.8 to prevent a lesser vulnerability, see the [logback JIRA Issue LOGBACK-1591](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1591) for details and a demo showing the exploit in [logbackRceDemo](https://github.com/cn-panda/logbackRceDemo). It has a lesser vulnerability, more info see [here](https://github.com/cn-panda/logbackRceDemo#summarize) and [here](http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html)

Comment: These articles have different opinion : 1.  http://slf4j.org/log4shell.html.  2. https://www.technology.pitt.edu/content/additional-guidance-regarding-log4j-vulnerability

Comment: @tryingToLearn we have used default configuration of logback which is provided by spring boot starters. We've not created any configuration file for logback. Is our system still vulnerable for RCE?

Comment: What does "starter" refer to? [Spring Boot built-in starters](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-starters)? Or something else?

Comment: The later versions of log4j2 do not have the vulnerability.